# microstrain_3dmgx2_imu

Tags: ros, microstrain-3dmgx2-imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with robot_location and microstrain_3dmgx2_imu. When I launch imu_node i have the same error about calibration, but when i do:
rosparam list to show the parameters that i can change, max_drift_rate not shown.
Where i have find it?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203822/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosparam list` will show parameters that are set, not parameters that are available.

You should be setting it in the launch file for the node. See https://github.com/husky/husky_bringup/blob/indigo-devel/launch/microstrain_config/microstrain.launch

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-02-27**:
thanks, i already do this and work successful